# How to highlight a link in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a search box on my page. When it is submitted it will jump to the anchor id further down the page based on the id entered into the text box, without refreshing the page (this is key).

Here is my current code.

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('form#unitid_quickfind').submit(function(e) {
        var anchor = $("#unitid_input").val();
        var position = $("#"+anchor).offset();
        window.scrollTo(position.left, position.top);

        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="unitid_quickfind">
    <input id="unitid_input" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Find" />
</form>

<a id="1">Unit 1</a>
<a id="2">Unit 2</a>
<a id="3">Unit 3</a>
```

Alongside jumping to the anchor when the submit is clicked, I would also like the link highlighted in some way. What is the easiest way to achieve this (preferably adding to the existing Javascript function)?

TIA

Comment: You can add a css like this : $("#"+anchor).addClass("highlight"); add remove class like this : $("#"+anchor).removeClass("highlight"); . Documentation here : https://api.jquery.com/addclass/ . It is to you to create the css you want.

Comment: You can do : $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight"); . With this, no needs to know which element is highlighted.

Comment: This should be enough to go on, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select that element and than you can simply apply the style you want.

Here i selected the element by `var element  = document.getElementById(anchor);` by this.

And by using `element.style.color = 'green'` i changes color of selected element.

```js
$(function() {
    $('form#unitid_quickfind').submit(function(e) {
        var anchor = $("#unitid_input").val();
        var position = $("#"+anchor).offset();
        var element  = document.getElementById(anchor);
        if(element)element.style.color = 'green'
        if(position)window.scrollTo(position.left, position.top);

        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form id="unitid_quickfind">
    <input id="unitid_input" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Find" />
</form>

<a id="1">Unit 1</a>
<a id="2">Unit 2</a>
<a id="3">Unit 3</a>
```